# why is comparing two values isn't working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a winning algorithm for a simple connect four game, this code is for checking if there is 4 same values in a horizontal line:

```
function win(clicked) {
    var cellco = clicked.className.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g); // example output:["col", "3", "row", "7"]
    var playervalue = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[cellco[3]].cells[cellco[1]].children[0];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var slot = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[cellco[3]].cells[i].children[0];
        if (slot == playervalue) {
            count++;console.log(count)//it only shows 1 even after having 4 objects
            if (count >=4) {
                return true;
            } else {
            count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The question sounds like you're asking about the comparison of two values, but there is a lot more going on in your code example than that. Can you perhaps create a minimal representation fo your issue?

Comment: This code will only check for 4 horizontal pieces in one row, what about vertical, or diagonal?

Comment: I want if there is 4 same 'playervalue' horizontally then return true

Comment: when I make this work everything else is easy, for vertical just change columns not rows ....

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> var count = 0;
> ```

The count starts at zero.

> ```
> count++;console.log(count)
> ```

You increment it and log it. It is now 1.

> ```
> if (count >=4) {
> ```

It is not. 1 is less than 4.

> ```
> count = 0;
> ```

You set it to zero.

(Then you go back to the step where you increment it to 1 and log it).

Comment: so how can i fix it in order for the algorithm to work? thanks btw

Comment: @Moswers — Move the `else` so it fires when there isn't a player piece in the space instead of when it finds one in a row.

Comment: I tried this: if (slot == pv) {
   count++;
   if (count >=4) {
    return true;
   }
  }
  else {count = 0} but it didn't work